# Payment Intents on Stripe Connected accounts on_behalf_of vs stripe-account header

Tags: stripe-payments

I am confused about the difference between passing in a stripe connect subaccount in the header vs using on_behalf_of and transfer_data[destination] as part of the POST form when using the Payment Intents API.

for payment intents - passing the subaccount as a header is ***NOT*** working while using 'on_behalf_of' does work

doing the below causes stripe to complain about a missing customer account though the customer was created on the main connect account:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
-u sk_test_XXX: \
-X POST \
-d amount=2000 \
-d currency=usd \
-d customer=cus_FROMBEFORE
-d capture_method=automatic
-d confirm=true
-d payment_method=pm_FROM_ELEMENTS
-H "stripe-account: acct_XXXX"
```

The below works:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents \
-u sk_test_XXX: \
-X POST \
-d amount=2000 \
-d currency=usd \
-d customer=cus_FROMBEFORE
-d capture_method=automatic
-d confirm=true
-d payment_method=pm_FROM_ELEMENTS
-d on_befalf_of=acct_XXXX
-d transfer_data[destination]=acct_XXX
```

is there a difference between the two approaches or can i use 'on_behalf_of' and not worry about the stripe fees/refunds/credit card statements etc. since they should all be under the sub account and not the connect account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Your first example is creating a [Direct Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges) which means the `charge` will be created on the connected account and requires the `customer` to exist on the connected account (you can also use [shared customers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers) to use a `customer` from your platform account). The funds will go directly to the connected account, Stripe's fees will be deducted, and your transaction fees will be taken out and sent to your platform.

Your second example, on the other hand, is creating a [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) where the `charge` will live on the platform account and use a `customer` that is also on the platform account. In this case, your platform will receive the funds, pay the Stripe fees, and then you transfer the amount you want to the connected account.

There's a [good summary of the options](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges) in Stripe's docs as well.

Comment: What am I missing here? Both of those scenarios sound identical...are they supposed to be? When is one more appropriate than another?

Comment: In the second example, stripe fee are paid by the platform.